# I am getting incorrect output from prime number script

Tags: python

Getting wrong output from this script.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

numbers = [1,3,5,7,8,25]


def primes():
    for i in numbers:
        if i > 1:
            if (i % 2) == 0:
                print "not prime"
            else :
                print "prime"
```

print primes()

its saying 25 is prime, any idea why ?

Comment: Maybe because 25 isn't even and your code is somewhat absurdly reporting all odd numbers to be prime?

Comment: @JohnColeman except `1`, to be fair!

Comment: Try stepping through the code, e.g. using http://www.pythontutor.com/ (or just a pen and paper) - the error should be pretty obvious.

Comment: Start out by figuring out common approaches to prime checking, before posting code that has little to do with that.  Then we'll probably be glad to help. A prime can't be even (except for 2) but not all odds are primes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your program is checking if numbers are odd, not if they're prime.
This is the validation you want (from [this page](http://www.programiz.com/python-programming/examples/prime-number))

```
# prime numbers are greater than 1
if num > 1:
   # check for factors
   for i in range(2,num):
       if (num % i) == 0:
           print(num,"is not a prime number")
           print(i,"times",num//i,"is",num)
           break
   else:
       print(num,"is a prime number")
```

Comment: this is for checking for numbers in a range are prime or not. i dont want to use a range, i am using a list of numbers

Comment: No it isn't. Please read the code more closely before complaining.

Comment: complaining ? was going to give points to you obviously , no need for the condescending attitude

Answer (score 1):

```
import math

numbers = [1,3,5,7,8,25]

def primes(n):
        if n == 2:
            return True
        if n%2 == 0 or n <= 1:
            return False
        sqr = int(math.sqrt(n)) + 1
        for divisor in range(3, sqr, 2):
            if n%divisor == 0:
                return False
        return True

for i in numbers:
    print i, '\t', primes(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code will just check for odd or even number. Not for prime number.